# Symfony2: Edit user without having password

Tags: php, security, symfony

In my application, only the admin user can create and, theoretically, edit users. So far, using only the Symfony security system (no FOSUserBundle management - its complexity is not required), creating users with varying roles is just fine.  The challenge that totally escapes me is how to edit a user without knowing the user's password.  I keep running into the expected validation error

> Password cannot be empty

.  How can editing be accomplished?  I'm surely missing something very fundamental here.

#### Edit action:

```
    public function editAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:User')->find($id);
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'user' => $user,
            'title' => 'Edit user',
            );
   }
```

#### Update action:

```
   public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:User')->find($id);
        $originalPassword = $user->getPassword();
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $plainPassword = $form->get('password')->getData();
            if (!empty($plainPassword))  {  
                //encode the password   
                $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($entity); //get encoder for hashing pwd later
                $tempPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt()); 
                $user->setPassword($tempPassword);                
            }
            else {
                $user->setPassword($originalPassword);
            }
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_main', array()));
        }
```

#### User form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('enabled', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => 'Enabled: ',
            ))
            ->add('fname')
            ->add('sname')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'invalid_message' => 'Password fields do not match',
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
            ))
            ->add('role', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('ROLE_USER' => 'User', 'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => 'Group: ',
            ))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until I see a more elegant solution, here's what I came up with:

1. Create a UserEditType form class with all fields but the password field(s)
2. Assign UserEditType to a validation group other than Default
3. Configure the password length constraint to the validation group in 2.
4. Modify the edit and update actions to use UserEditType

And now users can be edited without having the password!

#### UserEditType:

```
class UserEditType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('enabled', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'),
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Enabled: ',
                ))
                ->add('fname')
                ->add('sname')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('role', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('ROLE_USER' => 'User', 'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'),
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Group: ',
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array('edit'),
        ));
    }
```

#### Password in User entity:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="userpass", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Password may not be empty")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = "5",
 *      max = "12",
 *      minMessage = "Password must be at least 5 characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Password cannot be longer than than 12 characters",
 *      groups = {"Default"}
 * )
```

#### Update action:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:User')->find($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserEditType(), $user);
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_main', array()));
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user,
        'title' => 'Edit user',
    );
}
```

Comment: No problem. I am just having issues with this as my password in the edit area keeps getting saved as null when submitting the form :-(

Comment: For anyone else implementing this solution, Symfony has some documentation (using this exact scenario as an example) [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/validation/groups.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/validation_groups.html).

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem here in my project.

I solved it by removing the password field from the form just for my edit action.

So, in my `UserController`, I changed the `editAction`:

```
//find the line where the form is created
$editForm = $this->createForm(new UserType($this->container), $entity)
        ->remove('password'); //add this to remove the password field
```

Comment: I can not get this to work, could it be this requires that the assertion is on the form type element and not on the entity type? (just noticed this is very old, so never mind, that may be the reason)

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this (untested code)

My User entity has a password property mapped to DB
It also has a 'plainPassword' property, that is not mapped

```
class User {
  // mapped
  private string $username;

  // mapped
  private string $password;

  // not mapped - simple php property
  private string $plainPassword;
  
  // getters/setters
  ...
}
```

The form, uses the plainPassword property, not the mapped password.

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {
  ...
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('username', TextType::class)
      ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, ['required' => false])
  }
  ...
}
```

And then somewhere, controller in this example, we check if the plainPassword is not empty - thus the password is trying to be changed.

```
public function updateUserAction(User $user, Request $request)
{
  $form = $this->formFactory->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
  if($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      if(0 !== strlen($user->getPlainPassword()) {
        $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getPasswordHasher($user);

        $salt = rtrim(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(random_bytes(32))), '=');
        $user->setSalt($salt);

        $hashedPassword = $encoder->hash($user->getPlainPassword(), $user->getSalt());
        $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
        $user->setPlainPassword(null);
      }

      $this->em->persist($user);
      $this->em->flush();

      return $this->redirectToRoute('something');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `remove()` function then apply also at the form setting. At least in Symfony 3.3.  In this way you will avoid the password confirmation stated by `@pusle`  above:

```
        $form = $this->formFactory->createForm()->remove("current_password");
        $form->setData($user)->remove("current_password");
```

Here the whole method in the ProfileController of the FOSUserBundle. It works for me:

```
public function editDiffAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserBy(['id' => $id]);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $this->formFactory->createForm()->remove("current_password");
        $form->setData($user)->remove("current_password");

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);

            $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show_diff', array('id' => $user->getId() ));
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

            return $response;
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/edit_diff.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'user_id' => $user->getId(),
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add 'disabled' => 'disabled' and this field won't be taken into account.

Comment: A disabled field is not persisted.  Doing so in this case sets the password to null. This is not a desirable result.

Comment: Yes, it's not persisted so current password remains untouched in the db.

Comment: "...password remains untouched in the db..." is true if & only if the password field is not present in the form class.  A field presented in a form class but configured to be disabled in that class will have its value set to null.  I have confirmed this in an experiment.  Can you provide code that will demonstrate otherwise?

Comment: I'm using Doctrine2 with standard setters and getters and Symfony 2.7.10. Form code looks like follow: 

`class UserEditType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', null, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'login (min 3 chars)')))
            ->add('password', 'password', array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'min 6 chars'),
                    'disabled' => 'disabled'))
`

Comment: I have hashed password in db, after I added 'disabled' value in edit form this field wasn't changed after form submit, it works in my project. You can also read in Symfony2 documentation: "If you don't want a user to modify the value of a field, you can set the disabled option to true. Any submitted value *will be ignored*." So when it's ignored it can't be saved in db as null.

Comment: Ok, last thing :) I'm not using `$user->setPassword($v)` here but just `$em->persist($user);` so maybe if value is ignored then it's not persisted.

Comment: I cannot explain why the behavior you describe is different from my application's use of `'disabled' => 'disabled'`. There are multiple instances here in SO of users describing the loss of data when disabling a field.

Comment: If your code above is accurate, tell me what happens if you include `'disabled' => 'disabled'` within the `attr` array.  Above you show it outside the `attr` array, which would then allow password to be persisted.

Comment: If you look at the page source you'll note that when `'disabled' => 'disabled'` is outside the `attr` array it does not appear as an HTML attribute.  When inside it does appear in the HTML.

Comment: This is html tag:
`<input id="user_password" name="user[password]" disabled="disabled" required="required" placeholder="min 6 chars" type="password">`

You can var_dump $request->request->all() and you will see that password is not a part of the request so when you had $user entity with password then after form submit if you don't change it explicitly using setPassword method it won't be changed. I guess `$form->handleRequest($request);` is able to bind only fields that are a part of the request. It's should be clear now for you.

Comment: The behavior of the disabled attribute in my application has always been clear to me.  What shall remain a mystery that I no longer wish to solve or even understand is why it behaves differently in your application.

Comment: It's not only my application but general behaviour of Symfony2 form which I explained you in the previous comment. You don't have to write sarcastic comment when you don't understand something.

Comment: While I am equally certain you do not understand and sarcastic.  Be well.