# Prevent form fields from rendering

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm trying to control the rendering of password fields based on whether i'm editing an user or creating one. I'm doing this with a simple session boolean variable as follows:

```
{{ form_start(userForm) }}
    {{ form_errors(userForm) }}

    <div id="user-fg-email" class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(userForm.email) }}
        {{ form_errors(userForm.email) }}
        {{ form_widget(userForm.email) }}
    </div>

    {% if app.session.get('editingUser') == false %}
        <div id="user-fg-pp1" class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(userForm.plainPassword.first) }}
            {{ form_widget(userForm.plainPassword.first) }}
        </div>

        <div id="user-fg-pp2" class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(userForm.plainPassword.second) }}
            {{ form_errors(userForm.plainPassword.first) }}
            {{ form_widget(userForm.plainPassword.second) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div id="user-fg-role" class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(userForm.role) }}
        {{ form_errors(userForm.role) }}
        {{ form_widget(userForm.role) }}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>

{{ form_end(userForm) }}
```

However when this boolean is evaluated as true, which is supposed to prevent these fields from rendering, they are still being rendered assumingly by the later following form_end tag.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

edit:

if editingUser == true the password fields are actually rendered after the button, hence my assumption it's done so by the form_end tag.

Comment: are you using a `{else}` or `{elseif}` before `{endif}`? like explained here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html

Comment: Nope, only what you see there. I'll update my question with a more code block containing the whole form.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570002/how-to-make-form-rest-not-display-a-field-with-symfony2

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks friend

Comment: If preventing form fields doesn't help, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856396/symfony2-edit-user-without-having-password) has a technique for editing a user without having its password.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to specify Twig to not display all the rest of the fields which are not explicitly rendered in the form : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```